# How can I replace a string in a file with a value using loop in shell script?

Tags: shell

I'm new in writing shell script. I have the following shell script. I'm going to replace a string with a value dynamically using loop.

```
for i in $(seq 1 5)
     do
        sed 's/counter/$i/g' AllMarkers.R > newfile.R

     done
```

but this script replace `counter` with `$i` instead of `1` or `2` and .... It would be appreciated if anybody can tell me how can I replace `counter` with sequential numbers using loop.

Answer (score 0):

The variable interpolation is not performed inside the strings enclosed in single-quotes. (["Variable interpolation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) is the official name of the feature which substitutes variable reference, e.g. "$i", with its value, inside string.)

There are few possibilities how to work this around. Most common is this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5)
do
   sed 's/counter/'$i'/g' AllMarkers.R > newfile.R
done
```

Stop the single-quoted string before `$i`, put the `$i`, and then resume the single-quoted string. Variations of that would be:

```
# in case if $i might potentially contain spaces:
sed 's/counter/'"$i"'/g'

# in case if the whole expression to sed has no special characters:
sed "s/counter/$i/g"
```